# Need help deserializing json data

Tags: json, vb.net

i have the following json string

```
{
    "Count": 10,
    "Page": 0,
    "Queue": [
        {
            "id": "146648",
            "number": "96599004970"
        },
        {
            "id": "146647",
            "number": "96599004970"
        },
        {
            "id": "146646",
            "number": "96599004970"
        },
        {
            "id": "146645",
            "number": "96599004970"
        },
        {
            "id": "146644",
            "number": "96599004970"
        },
        {
            "id": "146643",
            "number": "96599004970"
        },
        {
            "id": "146642",
            "number": "96599004970"
        },
        {
            "id": "146641",
            "number": "96599004970"
        },
        {
            "id": "146640",
            "number": "96599004970"
        },
        {
            "id": "146639",
            "number": "96599004970"
        }
    ]
}
```

i'm using vb.net with newtonstoft json

i made these classes

```
Public Class Queue
    Public Property Count As Integer
    Public Property Page As Integer
    Public Property Msgs As List(Of Msg)
End Class

Public Class Msg
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property number As String
End Class
```

I used this code to deserialize this string

```
Dim getQueue as Queue
getQueue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Queue)(jsonString)
```

how can i rebuild the array? or retreive data from that queue object
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your json string deserialized properly, your mapping class should look like this instead :

```
Public Class RootObject
    Public Property Count As Integer
    Public Property Page As Integer
    Public Property Queue As List(Of Queue)
End Class

Public Class Queue
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property number As String
End Class
```

Then you can do as follow :

```
Dim getQueue as RootObject
getQueue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(jsonString)
For Each Q As Queue In getQueue.Queue
    'here you can access each Queue object
Next
```

NB: above class definitions are translated from C# classes generated using http://json2csharp.com/ tool. That is a handy online tool to generate classes suitable for mapping your json.

Answer (score 0):

try this. Sorry its in C# as I dont know VB.net

```
var JsonStr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Queue>(jsonString);
label1.Text = JsonStr.Count
label2.Text = JsonStr.Page
for (int i = 0; i < JsonStr.Msg.Count; i++)
{
    label3.Text = JsonStr.Msg[i].id;
    label4.Text = JsonStr.Msg[i].number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code prints `id` and `number` values for each `msg`s:

```
For Each msg As Msg In getQueue.Msgs
    Console.WriteLine("id: " + msg.id & ", number: " + msg.number)
Next
```